# How to fix 'NameError: sys not defined'

Tags: python, pygame

I have some Pygame code that is working fine up until I try to close the program. The program keeps telling me that sys is not defined. I am using the more python programming for the absolute beginner to get the hang of Pygame.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,500))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

My expected result is that the window will close but instead the window stays open and this error is spat out: NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: You need to import sys before using :-) - `import sys`

Comment: The dupe is more subtle than your issue, but it is good enough IMO

Answer (score 10):

`sys` is a module that you need to import, preferably at the beginning.

```
import sys
```